# How to stack up sticky headers with Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, layout, sticky

There are a few questions regarding this subject already, but I haven't found a good solution.

I am trying to create a long, scrolling page where the headers (which are also navigation) are sticky, stacking up under each other, when the viewport's top is reached.

I'll try to show it. `-----` is for  the viewport boundaries.

Initial state:

```
---------------
A


---------------
```

Scrolling down:

```
---------------
A

B
---------------
```

Stacking it up:

```
---------------
A
B

---------------
```

Ideally, when the viewport is full, stacking is given up:

```
---------------
D
E
F
---------------
```

This would be the left column of a bootstrap grid. On the right, there is related content being scrolled.

What I would like to avoid is to assign a pixel distance (from top of the viewport) to each stacked item, it should be resizeable and fluid.

Is there a simple solution? Is this doable at all? 
Please also post if you think it doesn't make sense at all.

Comment: I've looked at position:sticky and a few tries of polyfills, but haven't got further

Comment: You'll want to detect when the element is near the end of the page and once it is you'll position fixed it. When you do the calculations you'll need to add the height of the stacked elements to the calculations